# Proving the optimality of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I proposed an algorithm and I want to prove its optimality. It is not a greedy algorithm. I have the whole searching space $\mathcal{S}$ and I only search inside a subset of this searching space $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{S}$ and exclude the remaining search space. I know the logic behind excluding this should not violate the optimality of my algorithm. What kind of proof technique I should use to formally prove the optimality of my algorithm ? like contradiction or so on. Note : the optimal solution that can be produced by my algorithm is not unique.

Comment: If you do an exhaustive search inside the smaller search space, just prove your intuition that the exclusion of a part of it is always safe. In other words, somehow argue that an optimal solution can never reside in the part to be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

It's rarely possible to prove that an algorithm is optimal. You would have to show that your algorithm takes n steps, and for some reason solving the problem in less than n steps is impossible. Even for someone who is 100 times more intelligent than you and me together.

An example is finding the maximum of n random numbers, which can done in n steps, and n steps are required because if you read n-1 or fewer array elements, then you can't know whether the last one is greater than all other elements or not.